# Sublime Text 3 and Rails: manage an app on a remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3, sftp

I'm new to Sublime Text and recently discovered the wonderful [SFTP plugin](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) on Sublime Text 3, which lets you work with a local folder and sync it to a remote server directory.
I have some questions:

- is it possible to sync the folder automatically once files are created or deleted, either locally or remotely, instead of clicking everytime on `Sync Local -> Remote` or viceversa?
- is it possible to launch rails or rake commands from the Sublime console to the remote server and after that sync the local folder contents automatically?

My local machine runs Windows 10 whereas my remote server is a Ubuntu 16.04.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sync the folder automatically once files are created or deleted, either locally or remotely, instead of clicking everytime on Sync Local -> Remote or viceversa?

Yes, but only for the files changed locally. Check [upload_on_save](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings#setting-upload_on_save).

> Is it possible to launch rails or rake commands from the Sublime console to the remote server and after that sync the local folder contents automatically?

You cannot run such commands using a FTP client. You will need SSH access to the server for that.

A work around would be to set up a listener on your server that will trigger `rails` commands when files are changed.

Comment: So if I delete a file locally, the only way to delete it also on the remote directory is to do a manual `Sync Local -> Remote`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that's your only option. Though that shouldn't come up very often.